# how to stop componentDidUpdate infinite loop

Tags: javascript

Taking id from URL and then calling API but after calling the API and setting received Data to state ComponentDidUpdate goes into an infinite loop

```
class Category extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
  };

  async componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    let id = this.props.match.params.category;
    console.log(this.state.data);
    console.log(id);
    if (prevState !== this.state.data) {
      let catData = await axios.get(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`
      );
      console.log("api", catData);
      this.setState({
        data: catData,
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.catData);
    return <div className="category"></div>;
  }
}

export default Category;
```

Answer (score 0):

`prevState !== this.state.data` will be true forever, so I think you can change code to this:

```js
class Category extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
  };

  async componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    let id = this.props.match.params.category;
    console.log(this.state.data);
    console.log(id);
    if (prevState.data !== this.state.data) {
      let catData = await axios.get(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`
      );
      console.log("api", catData);
      this.setState({
        data: catData,
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.catData);
    return <div className="category"></div>;
  }
}

export default Category;
```